# Finding the control at run time when the name of the control is know in string

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I created a hyperlink dynamically as below

```
 Hyperlink objHyperlink = new Hyperlink();
```

depending on the key value i need to set the existing hyperlinks to objHyperlink

```
 if key == "Markets"
 then hyperlink to be set is  hyplnkIsActiveMarkets
 if key =="Budgets"
 then hyperlink to be set is  hyplnkIsActiveBudgets
```

My question is how can get control at runtime where i know name of it is "hyplnkIsActive"+"Markets"  ("Markets" is got from key)

Is der anything like `FindControlByname("hyplnkIsActive"+"Markets");`

Comment: Do you mean **Name == ID** ? Did you try using `FindControl` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var myControl = (Control)this.FindName("Control Name");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of all available hyperlinks then try this

```
Hyperlink FindLinkByName(IEnumerable<Hyperlink> links,string linkName)
{
  return links
        .FirstOrDefault
         ( 
            link => Equals(link.GetValue(FrameworkElement.NameProperty),linkName) 
         );
}
```

And you can call it like this:

```
FindLinkByName(list of links, "hyplnkIsActive"+"Markets")
```

Answer (score -1):

Save the created control in a hashtable with key and object.
this is the fasted method